# Python not writing to line by line

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6

Please help me to find cause , My code not writing to the file line by line, It is only writing last one of the loop.

Code --

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(lpath):
    f = open("filelist.txt","w")
    for name in fnmatch.filter(files, 'hdfs-audit.log.*'):
        filename = os.path.join(root, name)

        bname=ntpath.basename(filename)
        if os.stat(filename).st_mtime < (now - (xdays * 86400)):
            print(filename)
            f.write(filename)
            f.write("\n")
            print("file_mtime:" + str(os.stat(filename).st_mtime))
            print("now:" + str(now))
            print("now - xdays * 86400:" + str(now - (xdays * 86400)))
    f.close()
```

OutPut--

```
/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hdfs-audit.log.2017-03-21
file_mtime:1490068800.0
now:1490592233.67
now - xdays * 86400:1490505833.67
/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hdfs-audit.log.2017-03-20
file_mtime:1489982400.0
now:1490592233.67
now - xdays * 86400:1490505833.67
```

Only

```
/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hdfs-audit.log.2017-03-20
```

in the filelist.txt file, it does not not contain

```
/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hdfs-audit.log.2017-03-21
```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you do:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(lpath):
     f = open("filelist.txt","w")
```

Every time it loops `filelist.txt` gets recreated. Thus all the content it already contained got deleted.

You need to switch it around like this:

```
f = open("filelist.txt","w")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(lpath):
```

Remember to also move `f.close()` out of the loop.